# Is it OK to use == on enums in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, enums

Is it OK to use `==` on enums in Java, or do I need to use `.equals()`?  In my testing, `==` always works, but I'm not sure if I'm guaranteed of that.  In particular, there is no `.clone()` method on an enum, so I don't know if it is possible to get an enum for which `.equals()` would return a different value than `==`.

For example, is this OK:

```
public int round(RoundingMode roundingMode) {
  if(roundingMode == RoundingMode.HALF_UP) {
    //do something
  } else if (roundingMode == RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN) {
    //do something
  }
  //etc
}
```

Or do I need to write it this way:

```
public int round(RoundingMode roundingMode) {
  if(roundingMode.equals(RoundingMode.HALF_UP)) {
    //do something
  } else if (roundingMode.equals(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) {
    //do something
  }
  //etc
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Java enum members: == or equals()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals)

Comment: @assylias this question came first. Perhaps flag for ♦ attention, since I'm not really sure if the two should be merged.

Comment: @MattBall I think the answer to your question that quotes the JLS is the best answer, which is why I chose to close this one.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Just my 2 cents: Here is the code for Enum.java, as published by Sun, and part of the JDK:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
    implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {

    // [...]

    /**
     * Returns true if the specified object is equal to this
     * enum constant.
     *
     * @param other the object to be compared for equality with this object.
     * @return  true if the specified object is equal to this
     *          enum constant.
     */
    public final boolean equals(Object other) { 
        return this==other;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I guess if I had just thought to step into .equals() with the compiler I would have seen this...

Answer (score 77):

Yes, == is fine - there's guaranteed to be just a single reference for each value.

However, there's a better way of writing your round method:

```
public int round(RoundingMode roundingMode) {
  switch (roundingMode) {
    case HALF_UP:
       //do something
       break;
    case HALF_EVEN:
       //do something
       break;
    // etc
  }
}
```

An even *better* way of doing it is to put the functionality within the enum itself, so you could just call `roundingMode.round(someValue)`. This gets to the heart of Java enums - they're *object-oriented* enums, unlike the "named values" found elsewhere.

EDIT: The spec isn't very clear, but [section 8.9](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9) states:

> The body of an enum type may contain
>   enum constants. An enum constant
>   defines an instance of the enum type.
>   An enum type has no instances other
>   than those defined by its enum
>   constants.

Comment: I'd love to take your word for it, but if you could provide a link to some official documentation that'd be better...

Comment: switch isn't useful when there is a lot of overlap between different cases.  Also, RoundingMode is part of java.math, so I can't add a method to it.

Comment: Oh-- and you doubt Jon Skeet?  You haven't been around here very long ;)

Comment: enums in switch statements? Didn't know that was possible. I'll have to try it out one day.

Comment: Encapsulating logic within enums using abstract methods is the real power of enums. It makes your code much more robust; when you add a new enum value in the future, the compiler will force you to implement the relevant logic, you don't have to remember to add a case to multiple switch statements.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is as if you had created singleton instances for each value in the enum:

```
public abstract class RoundingMode {
  public static final RoundingMode HALF_UP = new RoundingMode();
  public static final RoundingMode HALF_EVEN = new RoundingMode();

  private RoundingMode() {
    // private scope prevents any subtypes outside of this class
  }
}
```

**However**, the `enum` construct gives you various benefits:

- Each instance's toString() prints the name given in code.
- (As mentioned in another post,) a variable of the enum type can be compared against constants using the `switch-case` control structure.
- All the values in the enumeration can be queried using the `values` field that is 'generated' for each enum type
- **Here's the big one w.r.t identity comparisons:** enum values survive serialization without cloning.

The serialization is a big gotchya. If I were to use the code above instead of an enum, here's how identity equality would behave:

```
RoundingMode original = RoundingMode.HALF_UP;
assert (RoundingMode.HALF_UP == original); // passes

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(original);
oos.flush();

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
RoundingMode deserialized = (RoundingMode) ois.readObject();

assert (RoundingMode.HALF_UP == deserialized); // fails
assert (RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN == deserialized); // fails
```

You *can* address this issue without enum, using a technique that involves `writeReplace` and `readResolve`, (see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)...

I guess the point is -- Java goes out of its way to allow you use enum values' identities for testing equality; it is an encouraged practice.

Comment: serialization bug was fixed. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6277781

Comment: @DavidI. thanks for the update. That's a very disturbing bug, and good to know!

Comment: @DilumRanatunga I thought this was going to affect me at first, but they appear to be working OK after passing them over an RMI connection.

Answer (score 11):

== compares the references of two objects. For enums, it is guaranteed that there will only be one instance, and therefore for any two enums that are the same, == will be true.

Reference:

http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2007/java/making-the-most-of-java-50-enum-tricks

(couldn't find anything in the Sun docs)

Answer (score 6):

Here is some evil code you might find interesting. :D

```
public enum YesNo {YES, NO}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) field.get(null);
    YesNo yesNo = (YesNo) unsafe.allocateInstance(YesNo.class);

    Field name = Enum.class.getDeclaredField("name");
    name.setAccessible(true);
    name.set(yesNo, "YES");

    Field ordinal = Enum.class.getDeclaredField("ordinal");
    ordinal.setAccessible(true);
    ordinal.set(yesNo, 0);

    System.out.println("yesNo " + yesNo);
    System.out.println("YesNo.YES.name().equals(yesNo.name()) "+YesNo.YES.name().equals(yesNo.name()));
    System.out.println("YesNo.YES.ordinal() == yesNo.ordinal() "+(YesNo.YES.ordinal() == yesNo.ordinal()));
    System.out.println("YesNo.YES.equals(yesNo) "+YesNo.YES.equals(yesNo));
    System.out.println("YesNo.YES == yesNo " + (YesNo.YES == yesNo));
}
```

Comment: @Peter can you please include the imports of this code? Cound not find `Unsafe.class`.

Answer (score 3):

Enums are a great place to jam polymorphic code.

```
enum Rounding {
  ROUND_UP {
    public int round(double n) { ...; }
  },
  ROUND_DOWN {
    public int round(double n) { ...; }
  };

  public abstract int round(double n);
}

int foo(Rounding roundMethod) {
  return roundMethod.round(someCalculation());
}

int bar() {
  return foo(Rounding.ROUND_UP);
}
```

Comment: Yes but I don't own java.math.RoundingMode, so I can't do this in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is problem when transfering enum via RMI/IIOP. See this thread:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t390342-enum-equality.html

Comment: This was http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6277781 which is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

== is generally okay, and there are advantages to both == and `.equals()`. I personally prefer to always use `.equals()` when comparing Objects, including `enum`s. See also this discussion:

[Comparing Java enum members: == or equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals)