# Hard coding a hashtable inside a class, how to do this in a thread safe manner?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to initialize a hashtable inside my class only once for my web application.

How can you do this in a thread-safe manner in case?

```
public class MySettings {

   private HashTable<int, SomeObject> settings;

}
```

Should it be marked static or final or volatile?
Do I wrap it in a synchronize?

Also, how can I set the properties of SomeObject inline?  Is it possible in java?

Comment: You're got an illegal declaration there: You can't specify `int` as a generic type. Try `Integer`

Comment: *"Also, how can I set the properties of SomeObject inline? Is it possible in java?"* - totally orthogonal to your real question.  Ask it in a different Question ... and take the time to expand on what you are really asking ...

Answer (score 3):

Make it static, final, initialize it and use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

You can even have a singleton class for this, and make it lazy.

Something like this. But again, use ConcurrentHashmap. Dont use Hashtable.

import java.util.*;

```
class Foo { 
        private static final Foo foo = new Foo(); 
        public static final Hashtable table = new Hashtable(); 
        private Foo(){} 

        public static Foo Instance(){
            return foo;
        }

}
```

Comment: FYI, here's a fun example:
class Foo { 
private static final Foo foo = new Foo();
private static final HashTable table = new HashTable();
private Foo(){
System.out.println(table);
}
}

Guess what that prints?

Comment: doenst print. there is no HashTable, should be Hashtable.

Comment: I edited and put the code. that must work right? you made me typed that. i m lazier than u .

Comment: That works. I was just pointing out that if you reference table in the constructor of Foo, it would be null.

Comment: well that s a private contsructor, to ensure that the class wont be initalized by another class and even subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to initialize a hashtable inside my class only once for my web application.

If you only want there to be one instance for your webapp then your choices are:

- a bare `static` (nasty!!),
- a `static` wrapped by a class with static methods (nasty, and awkward to use),
- an `static` wrapped using the Singleton class pattern (not so nasty / awkward, but not without problems), or
- a shared instance that is created and injected using a dependency injection (DI) framework.

The last is best from a number of perspectives, but it entails changing your webapp to use DI, which will be disruptive.

So I suggest that you read up on the Singleton class pattern and how to implement it in Java so that it is *created and initialized* in a thread-safe fashion:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
- [Thread safety in Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912281/thread-safety-in-singleton)

Then there is the separate question/issue of how you *use* the hash table in a thread-safe fashion.  And the answers/solutions depend on *how* your application is going to use the hash table once it has been initialized.

- If the webapp only ever reads the hash table, then a plain `HashMap` is sufficient.
- If the webapp needs to read and update the hash table, then the choice is between a `ConcurrentHashMap` or a synchronized wrapper for a regular `HashMap`.

  - If the table is likely to have lots of threads wanting to perform operations (i.e. lock contention is a likely issue), OR if you need to be able to iterate the table entries while updates *might* be happening, then use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.
  - Otherwise, a `HashMap` with a synchronization wrapper will be sufficient.