# Singleton Implementation example

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am trying to find my own way of Java Singleton implementation.
The code is as follows:

```
public class Singleton{
   private volatile static Singleton _instance = null;
   private Singleton(){}
   public static Singleton getInstance(){
      if (_instance == null)
         Object obj = new Object();
         synchronized(obj){
            if (_instance == null)
               _instance = new Singleton();
         }
      return _instance;
}
```

Does this code work?
If not work, how to fix it?

Comment: You are using a method local lock, which totally invalidates your synchronization (effectively, there is none).

Comment: You should have a look at `Jon Skeet's` singleton implementation. Pretty much covers your issue.

Comment: Here is another question, showing Skeet's method mentioned above [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912281/thread-safety-in-singleton]

Comment: @Perception Could you explain in more details?

Comment: what Perception is saying is that, if synchronized always locks on a new object, there's no way other threads will be contending for the same lock. So it doesn't limit concurrent access at all.

Comment: [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not correct, you should synchronize on Singleton.class

```
class Singleton {
       private volatile static Singleton _instance;
       private Singleton(){}
       public static Singleton getInstance(){
          if (_instance == null)
             synchronized(Singleton.class){
                if (_instance == null)
                   _instance = new Singleton();
             }
          return _instance;
    }
}
```

it's a known double-checked locking pattern, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html for details

Note that since there's only one method in this class the following serves the same purpose without any double-checked tricks and it's lazy too

```
class Singleton {
       private static Singleton _instance = new Singleton();
       private Singleton(){}
       public static Singleton getInstance(){
          return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi double-checked locking is considered an anti-pattern

Comment: and your second example is not lazy. the instance will be created when the class is first required to be loaded, not necessarily used

Comment: @Bohemian but it is lazy, it's similar to "lazy initialization holder class idiom" from Effective Java

Comment: It is *not* lazy. As I said before, the instance will be created when the class is *loaded*, not when `getInstance()` is first called. It may be loaded due to a dependency long before it is needed, often at server start up, which is why the holder idiom is used - with it the class may be loaded *without* creating the singleton instance.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Actually, the singleton class might have other members, i.e. other public static variable which is the real usage of singleton

Comment: @bohemian Why you said double-checked locking is considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: @bohemian the Singleton class here, there is only one way of access it, by calling the getInstance method. So only when calling this method, the class is loaded. I cannot find other ways of loading Singleton class.

Comment: @assylias Actually, you *do* need the `volatile` keyword, otherwise you get the "double checked locking anti-pattern" problem, due to the java memory model not requiring that writes "happens before" reads for non-volatile fields. See [this article](http://reentrantthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/on-why-double-check-locking-in-anti.html) for more

Comment: @Zack See [this famous article](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) for the reason it's called an anti-pattern. In later version of java, the volatile keyword and a change to the java memory model specification resurrected this pattern back to the living (see [this article](http://reentrantthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/on-why-double-check-locking-in-anti.html), but it's inferior to the holder idiom (see my answer)

Comment: @Zack Regarding class being loaded *before* calling `getInstance()`, *any* reference to the class, even the `Singleton.class` object, perhaps due to a logging initialization parameter or an `instanceof Singleton` test or whatever, will cause the class to be loaded, which can be *long* before the `Singleton.getInstance()` method is called.

Comment: @Bohemian You only need volatile in his first example, not in his second example.

Comment: @assylias Right. Must have skimmed (again) :)

Answer (score 3):

No - your code doesn't work, because the lock object is a local variable and therefore different for every thread.

You are attempting to implement the [*lazy initialization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) pattern - where the instance is created when first used.

But there is a simple trick that allows you to code a thread-safe implementation that *doesn't* require synchronization! It is known as the [*Initialization-on-demand holder idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), and it looks like this:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static class Holder {
        static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private Singleton() {
    }

    // rest of class omitted
}
```

This code initializes the instance on the first calling of `getInstance()`, and importantly dosen't need synchronization because of the contract of the class loader:

- the class loader loads classes when they are first accessed (in this case `Holder`'s only access is within the getInstance()` method)
- when a class is loaded, and before anyone can use it, all static initializers are guaranteed to be executed (that's when `Holder`'s static block fires)
- the class loader has its own synchronization built right in that make the above two points guaranteed to be threadsafe

It's a neat little trick that I use whenever I need lazy initialization. You also get the bonus of a `final` instance, even thought it's created lazily. Also note how clean and simple the code is.

Answer (score 2):

Ticky and really simple implementation of not-lazy singleton:

```
public enum TickySingleton {

    INSTANCE;

    public void doSomething() { ... }
    public Object returnSomething() { ... }
}
```

}

Not everybody will like this. ;)

Comment: I just found out someone wrote about that implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912281/thread-safety-in-singleton

Comment: This 'enum singleton pattern' is also recommended by Josh Bloch in the book 'Effective Java'

Answer (score 1):

it would be better if your synchronization object is `final static`. Otherwise each possible concurrent thread will create its own sync object and lock different objects. And they will not wait for each other.

```
public class Singleton{

   private final static Object obj = new Object();
   private volatile static Singleton _instance = null;

   private Singleton(){}

   public static Singleton getInstance(){
     if (_instance == null)
        synchronized(obj){
           if (_instance == null)
              _instance = new Singleton();
         }
      }
      return _instance;
   }
```

Comment: Yes. I find my problem. The object can not be in the method. Otherwise, each time the method is called, a new different object is created. Does not work.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
Object obj = new Object();
synchronized(obj){}
```

The JVM can prove that no two threads can acquire that lock (because it is a local variable) and can therefore completely remove the synchronization.

A few comments about singletons:

- in most cases, [you don't really need them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)
- they will be a pain later on, [particularly for testing (see section called: "Flaw: Brittle Global State & Singletons")](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf)
- if you really do need a singleton, [use an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java) which is the easiest, thread-safe, lazy way to create a singleton