# Singleton design pattern class with multiple types of instance variables

Tags: java, singleton

Is it ok to declare multiple instance variables (Has-A relationships with other classes) in a singleton class?

```
class Singleton {

private static Singleton obj;
Student student;
School school;

private Singleton() {}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (obj==null)
        obj = new Singleton();
    return obj;
 }
}
```

Comment: What would be the problem ? You can't use Singleton pattern only with no attribut class, that would no real usage

Comment: Note that this method of creating the singleton instance is not thread safe. There are many discussions of this issue on this site and others. Here’s one good one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2912281/29470

Comment: What do you mean by OK? Do you mean valid, runnable code? Or something else?