# The best way to compare enums

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum, for example `enum Color { Red, Brown }`.  I also have some variables of that type:

```
Color c1 = Brown, c2 = Red
```

What is best way to compare to a constant value:

```
if (c1 == Color.Brown) { 
    //is brown
}
```

or

```
if (c1.equals(Color.Brown)) {
    //is brown
}
```

Comment: Either is fine, but I think for simplicity's sake, I go with ==.

Comment: I'd go with `.equals(...)` because it makes me happier. :D

Comment: I prefer to put the constant on the left. That way if you accidentally put = you get a compiler error.  Color.Brown==c1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals

Comment: FYI, anyone interested in this Question may find the [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and `EnumMap` classes useful.

Comment: `equals` accepts an `Object` and so there is less type safety compared to `==`

Answer (score 13):

Use `==`.  There cannot be multiple instances of the same enum constant (within the context of a classloader, but let's ignore that point) so it's always safe.

That said, using `equals()` is safe too, and will perform reference equality as well.  It's pretty much a style choice.

Personally I very seldom find myself using `if` statements for enums at all.  I favour `switch` blocks.

```
switch (c1) {
    case Brown:
        //is brown
        break;
    case Red:
        //...
}
```

Comment: That code snippet makes me a sad panda. D:

Comment: @Moonbeam: Why is that?  Obviously it's a contrived example, but it's the OP's example, not mine.

Comment: Use == because enums variables are allowed to be null.  There is no reason IMO to use equals()