# How do I compare two enums?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum named PawnColor which simply contains the following:

```
public enum PawnColor {
    black, white, none, illegal
}
```

If I had the following method, how could I check the color of the current instance of PawnColor?

```
public double ratePosition (PawnColor ratingFor)  {
    // ...
}
```

So if `ratingFor` had the color: `illegal`, how could I go about checking this? I've never worked with enums before, I feebly tried doing:

```
if(ratingFor.equals(illegal)) {
    System.out.println("Something has gone wrong.");
}
```

It didn't work obviously, how would I make sure that I get an error message when PawnColor ratingFor is illegal?

Comment: Why not just read a tutorial on enums? There are plenty, and you'll save yourself time in the long run...

Comment: I tried one that looked as easy as it was simple but it did not work at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875677/the-best-way-to-compare-enums?rq=1

Comment: @MattAndrzejczuk what did you get? exception? no error message?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this locally and error message is printed correctly.

```
PawnColor ratingFor = PawnColor.illegal;
if(ratingFor == PawnColor.illegal)
{
    System.out.println("Something has gone wrong.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if (ratingFor == illegal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer `illegal` as `PawnColor.illegal`.

Simply use `==` as :

```
   if(ratingFor == PawnColor.illegal)
```

You may also use `equals` as:

```
   if(PawnColor.illegal.equals(ratingFor))
```

Answer (score 0):

For enum constants, equals and == amount to the same thing, and can be used **interchangeably**

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ratingFor.equals(illegal)) {
    System.out.println("Something has gone wrong.");
}
```

Here you can not reference "illegal", ratingFor can only be compared to type PawnColor.class.

```
ratingFor == PawnColor.illegal
```

or

```
ratingFor.equals(PawnColor.illegal)
```

will give you the desired result