# Double click is not being caught by OnMouseEvent (JavaFX2)

Tags: javafx-2

Double clicks are being captured as single click :(

In fxml file:

```
<Button fx:id="A_button" onMouseClicked="#buttonAClicked">
```

In the controller

```
private void buttonAClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
            System.out.println("Double clicked A_button");
        }
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1) {
            System.out.println("Single clicked A_button");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am finding that double click is not being caught - only single clicks.
In the debugger, click count is 1.

**Update:**
Since I cant figure out why it is not working for me on JavaFX 2.2.3-b05, I did a workaround and removed the need for double-click. I added a "Load" button to the UI. Now user must single click AND press the load button.

Comment: I have tested your code in 2.2.0-b21, and it is working as expected. Both single and double clicks are fired.

Comment: for me: VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion(); 2.2.3-b05

Answer (score 2):

It was fixed in JavaFX 2.2, see http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19346

Note, that on double click you will receive two events:

- mouse click with getClickCount() == 1
- mouse click with getClickCount() == 2

E.g. if you run code below and double click on button output would be:

```
clicks: 1
clicks: 2
```

Code (tested with 2.2.4):

```
public class DoubleClicks extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("clicks: " + event.getClickCount());
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(btn), 300, 250));
        stage.setTitle(VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

Comment: I double-clicked the button and then in the mousehandler breakpoint, inspected the MouseEvent. It has a variable click count, the value of which is 1. I got only one event in the debugger - but let me try again to see if I get another event.c

Comment: I tested your information but found that I got only one event. I did not put it into debug mode, just ran it in the IDE and got as output: `Single clicked A_button`. No other statement.

Comment: Sergey. What about if the user wants to do a different jobs at single and double clicks on the same node. Currently, user cannot pick out only the double click in the code similar to the above.

Comment: @Anil: I've updated answer with code sample. Please, compare your code and fx version

Comment: @UlukBiy system can't be sure if click is just a single click or a double click until double click timeout is passed. And timeout can be set to something huge like 10 seconds in settings. You really don't want to make user wait seconds on every click before your program responds. Thus you need to design events reaction with 2 events in mind. E.g. Windows Explorer select file on single click and select AND open file on double click, so there is no issue for a user.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks for updating your code sample. To compare, your handler is registered at runtime which is probably different from registering in fxml. That is the only difference I see.

Comment: @Uluk and Sergey, thanks for your help. I have devised a workaround by adding a button to the UI - please see question for details