# Disable TreeItem's default expand/collapse on double click JavaFX 2.2

Tags: java, treeview, mouseevent, javafx-2, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX 2.2 project and i want to set custom handling of the mouse (double) click event on a TreeItem. Using **treeview.setOnMouseClicked** i fire my code without errors but the problem is that the TreeItem, on every mouse double click, it toggles between expanded and collapsed. I suppose that this is the default behavior, but how i disable it??

Comment: Try to look at the forum before...

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/10950824/2170935][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10950824/2170935

Comment: My problem is the default double click behavior of the TreeItem not the detection of the mouse click event. With the treeview.setOnMouseClicked i detect the event without problem but this is not what i am looking for. TreeItems, on double click, are by default expanding and collapsing themselves, this is my problem. I want to disable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it in time using `EventDispatcher`.

```
class TreeMouseEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher {
    private final EventDispatcher originalDispatcher;

    public TreeMouseEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher originalDispatcher) {
      this.originalDispatcher = originalDispatcher;
    }

    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
        if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
           if (((MouseEvent) event).getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY
               && ((MouseEvent) event).getClickCount() >= 2) {

             if (!event.isConsumed()) {
               // Implement your double-click behavior here, even your
               // MouseEvent handlers will be ignored, i.e., the event consumed!
             }

             event.consume();
           }
        }
        return originalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
    }
}
```

and then use this `TreeMouseEventDispatcher` for the `TreeCell`:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<T>, TreeCell<T>>() {
  @Override
  public TreeCell<T> call(TreeView<T> param) {
    return new TreeCell<T>() {
      @Override
      protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        if (item != null && !empty) {
          EventDispatcher originalDispatcher = getEventDispatcher();
          setEventDispatcher(new TreeMouseEventDispatcher(originalDispatcher));
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to use this as well!

Comment: This answer only really works by accident! Because it is broken in another way. I'm adding another answer to explain the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that though Bolg's answer works, it isn't strictly the "correct" way to do it, and may cause some unexpected behaviour.

The cause of this issue is described in [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092146). To summarise: the default double click behaviour of a tree cell is actually precipitated by the mouse *press* event, so it's too late to consume the event and block it within a mouse *click* listener.

The reason the accepted answer works is that it doesn't filter on the mouse event *type*, meaning it consumes all mouse events relating to the primary button and a click count of two. This also means that the user action is processed three times, which is probably not the intended behaviour.

The fix is only a single line change to Bolg's answer, but I think it is probably better not to involve an EventDispatcher. Something like the following should work just fine:

```
node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
    if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
        if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED)) {
            System.out.println("hello"); // perform some action
        }

        event.consume();
    }
});
```