# JavaFX TreeView: remove expand / collapse button (disclosure node) & functionality

Tags: javafx, treeview, disabled-control, disclosure

I want to have a TreeView that has all of its children permanently expanded, and I don't want the user to be able to expand or collapse any of the children.

To do this I've found that I need to do the following:

- Remove icon with CSS (Done)

  - [Change expand and collapse image TreeView JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521806/change-expand-and-collapse-image-treeview-javafx-2-2)
  - [edit] Above link should be used to change image; to remove completely, use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27831191/4430591
- Remove double click functionality (Done)

  - [Disable TreeItem's default expand/collapse on double click JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509203/disable-treeitems-default-expand-collapse-on-double-click-javafx-2-2)
- [edit] Remove ability to collapse / expand using keyboard arrrow keys (Done)

  - Given in José Pereda's solution below ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/27831085/4430591 )
- [edit] Remove ability to right click for a ContextMenu (Done)

  - Given in José Pereda's solution below ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/27831085/4430591 )
- **Remove icon's clickablity (How do I do this?)**

  - [edit] solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27831191/4430591

Even though the icon is no longer visible, it's still clickable. I don't see any way of filtering this; I only see ways to be able to respond to it after the fact.

Also, if I'm missing anything else that I need to do to ensure this functionality, please let me know.

Comment: Do the tree items have any functionality at all (i.e. they can be clicked, with some custom action)?

Comment: Yes; I implemented a custom TreeCell & set that as my cell factory. I'm  not concerned with being able to start/cancel/commit edits, as my graphic for each TreeCell is a FlowPane with various ComboBoxes and other controls for the various underlying models that the cells are displaying.

I still want them to be able to clicked, highlighted, and dragged though.

Comment: Is there possibly any way to remove the entire hit stage of the collapse button with CSS? I'd even settle with that at this point...

Comment: CSS just defines the view, but you want to alter the behavior. If you could provide your own skin implementation... `TreeCellSkin` extends `TreeCellBehavior`, which, at the end, is the class that handles all the clicking via `handleClicks` and `handleDisclosureNode`. But I'm not sure you want to go there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel quite silly. I think this was mostly just a matter of not knowing what that darn arrow was called. Apparently it's a disclosureNode? Maybe that's common knowledge.

In the custom defined TreeCell, all I did was add this line in the updateItem method:

```
setDisclosureNode(null);
```

Comment: Hi.. it would be bit helpful, if you explain how you define custom treeCell

Answer (score 1):

The solution to avoid modifying the skin or the default behavior is more simple if we trap the clicks before they are dispatched, and consume the right ones.

For that we can use an `EventDispatcher`, to filter both the mouse pressed and the right click over the arrows, which are `StackPane` nodes:

```
class CellEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher {

    private final EventDispatcher original;

    public CellEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
        if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) || 
             event.getEventType().equals(ContextMenuEvent.ANY)){
            event.consume();
        }
        if(event instanceof KeyEvent && event.getEventType().equals(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)){
            if((((KeyEvent)event).getCode().equals(KeyCode.LEFT) || 
                 ((KeyEvent)event).getCode().equals(KeyCode.RIGHT))){
                event.consume();
            }
        }
        return original.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
    }
}
```

Now we apply our custom dispatcher to the tree view:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>();
    ...
    EventDispatcher treeOriginal = tree.getEventDispatcher();
    tree.setEventDispatcher(new CellEventDispatcher(treeOriginal));

    Scene scene = new Scene(tree);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show(); 
}
```

This will consume any click (left or right) over the arrows on the tree.

**EDIT**

Added to the event dispatcher class the case where the user uses the keyboard to traverse the tree view, consuming the collapse/expand events with arrow `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.

Comment: Wouldn't this create a scenario where if the disclosure node (little arrow) where still there (although possibly invisible in my case), the user would click the invisible button, and the mouse click event would be consumed without the TreeItem being selected?

Comment: Well, what you could do is just trigger the action for that treeItem (you'll have to find which item was clicked, though)

Comment: Just added to the event dispatcher class the case where the user uses the keyboard to traverse the tree view, consuming the collapse/expand events with arrow `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.

Comment: ContextMenuEvent.ANY portion doesn't appear to work. I'm having it just print every event it gets & all I see it mouse events. I never see anything yield any ContextMenuEvents.

The KeyEvent portion was very helpful though

Comment: ContextMenuEvent happens when you right click to show a posible `ContextMenu`. In my simple snippet I could stop it. With the rest of your code maybe it's already disabled.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood. Right clicking -- Got it. I removed the "(event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) ||" portion though; This wasn't needed. Otherwise It's running quite nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, glad it works. I've just fixed some wrong formatting

Answer (score 0):

Here's the real answer to the question that was asked. Change the disclosure node to an identical one that doesn't have any click behavior. Just create two `StackPanes` with the same style classes as the original and the default stylesheet will handle the rest, including rotating the node when the item is expanded.

```
StackPane arrow = new StackPane();
arrow.getStyleClass().add("arrow");
StackPane disclosureNode = new StackPane(arrow);
disclosureNode.getStyleClass().add("tree-disclosure-node");
cell.setDisclosureNode(disclosureNode);
```