# JavaFX8: Treeview, get mouseclick on icon or text

Tags: javafx, treeview, icons, label, mouseevent

Can I get different mouse-click events from a TreeViewItem depending on the user clicks on the icon or on the text label? The icon is not the collapse image of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Disable TreeItem's default expand/collapse on double click JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509203/disable-treeitems-default-expand-collapse-on-double-click-javafx-2-2) I have changed the constructor of the TreeMouseEventDispatcher:

```
class TreeMouseEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher {
    private final EventDispatcher originalDispatcher;
    private final TreeCell<?> cell;

    public TreeMouseEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher originalDispatcher, TreeCell<?> cell) {
      this.originalDispatcher = originalDispatcher;
      this.cell = cell;
    }

    private boolean isMouseEventOnGraphic(Node icon, Point2D coord) {
        if (icon == null) {
           return false;
        }
        return icon.localToScene(icon.getBoundsInLocal()).contains(coord);
    }

    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
        if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
           MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
           if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY
               && mouseEvent.getClickCount() >= 2) {

             if (!mouseEvent.isConsumed()) {
                if (isMouseEventOnGraphic(cell.getGraphic(), new Point2D(mouseEvent.getSceneX(), mouseEvent.getSceneY()))) {
                   // action for double click on graphic
                } else {
                   // action for double click on all other elements of
                   // the TreeCell (like text, text gap, disclosure node)
                }
             }
             event.consume();
           }
        }
        return originalDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
    }
}
```

and then use this `TreeMouseEventDispatcher` for the `TreeCell`:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<T>, TreeCell<T>>() {
  @Override
  public TreeCell<T> call(TreeView<T> param) {
    return new TreeCell<T>() {
      @Override
      protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        if (item != null && !empty) {
          EventDispatcher originalDispatcher = getEventDispatcher();
          setEventDispatcher(new TreeMouseEventDispatcher(originalDispatcher, this));
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```