# Disable TreeItem's default expand/collapse on double click (JavaFX 8)

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, javafx-8

How do I disable the default expand/collapse behaviour when double clicking a TreeItem in a TreeView?

*My question is exactly the same as this one: [Disable TreeItem's default expand/collapse on double click JavaFX 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509203/disable-treeitems-default-expand-collapse-on-double-click-javafx-2-2)
Unfortunately the provided answers don't work anymore (if they ever did).*

UPDATE 1: 
Unfortunately I didn't know that it is important to mention that I don't use the standard `TreeItem`, but a modified one. Its constructor looks like this:

```
public BasicTreeItem(String text) {
  super();

  _label = new Label(text);
  stateIndicator = new ImageView();
  this.setToNever(); // sets the stateIndicator mentioned above

  _hb = new HBox();
  this.setValue(_hb);
  _hb.getChildren().add(stateIndicator);
  _hb.getChildren().add(_label);
  _hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
}
```

So the thing that is seen in the end is the HBox.

Comment: curious: why do you want to change standard (at least on win) UX? typical users are not happy about such tweaks ;)

Comment: My TreeItems consist of a special CheckBox with 4 different states which I want to change quickly. If I click too fast on them, the TreeItems expands/collapses, which I don't want to. But if I doubleclick on the Label, I still want the item to expand / collapse.

Comment: thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can for example use the [`CellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) of the `TreeView` to attach an `EventFilter` on mouse listener to the [`TreeCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeCell.html)s of the tree.

**Example:**

```
public class TreeViewExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        TreeView tw = new TreeView();
        TreeItem rootNode = new TreeItem("Root");
        TreeItem blockOne = new TreeItem("Block1");
        TreeItem childA = new TreeItem("ChildA");
        TreeItem childB = new TreeItem("ChildB");
        blockOne.getChildren().add(childA);
        blockOne.getChildren().add(childB);
        TreeItem blockTwo = new TreeItem("Block2");
        TreeItem childC = new TreeItem("ChildC");
        TreeItem childD = new TreeItem("ChildD");
        blockTwo.getChildren().add(childC);
        blockTwo.getChildren().add(childD);
        rootNode.getChildren().add(blockOne);
        rootNode.getChildren().add(blockTwo);
        tw.setRoot(rootNode);


        tw.setCellFactory(param -> {
            TreeCell<String> treeCell = new TreeCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText("");
                        setGraphic(null);
                        return;
                    }

                    setText(item.toString());
                }
            };

            treeCell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
                if (e.getClickCount() % 2 == 0 && e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
                    e.consume();
            });
            return treeCell;
        });

        root.getChildren().add(tw);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TreeView!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

**Update for your particulat use case:**

First of all, your `TreeItem` implementation is really strange, as it must be something like:

```
class BasicTreeItem extends TreeItem<HBox>
```

It's a bad practice to use GUI elements as model. You could implement a class that is able to store all the states that each item can have, and use that class as model for the `TreeView` and also as generic parameter for your `BasicTreeItem` implementation.

But to answer the update question: If you want to have the double-click expand behaviour when the `Label` is double clicked, but you dont want to have it if the `ImageView` is double clicked.

In this case you can r**emove the `CellFactory` completely** and add the `EventFilter` to the `ImageView` (e.g. in your `BasicTreeItem` constructor):

```
stateIndicator.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
    if (e.getClickCount() % 2 == 0 && e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
        e.consume();
});
```

With this fitler your `TreeItem` will have the standard double-click behaviour except double clicking on the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I forgot to mention that I use an own version of TreeItem, which I added now to the original question. If you know how to `setCellFactory` for that, I would be more than happy :)

Comment: That did it :). In my next project, I will surely not use GUI elements as model anymore, but right now I've come to far to rework everything.

Comment: Just to make it clear, what did you mean by "It's a bad practice to use GUI elements as model."? Is it because of the use of `HBox`` (which is actually just used to show the relevant information in the `TreeView` or because I store data within the `TreeItem`? Basically I'm wondering if `TreeItem` would be a model where I can store data (by extending the `TreeItem`class) or even take more of them to store a tree-like structure of data.

Comment: Thanks! I had wondered why my attempt wasn't working. I was filtering MOUSE_CLICKED events not MOUSE_PRESSED,