# How to check equals on enum value?

Tags: java, enums

How can I check equality on a value of an enum? I tried the following, but it fails. WHy?

```
class enum Test {
    LETTER("1A");

    private String value;
    public Test(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void toString() {
        return value;
    }
}


String teststring = "1A".
Sysout(teststring.equals(Test.LETTER)); //false. Why???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison is returning `false` because you're comparing a `String` instance with an `Enum` instance.

@RohitJain already gave a great explanation about why the `toString()` method doesn't get called in your comparison in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19586384/851811), and how you should use it if it's what you want to do.

However, `toString()` shouldn't be used for comparison purposes, it should be overriden only to provide a custom String representation of the object.

You could compare the property you're really intereseted in comparing if you do this:

```
String teststring = "1A".
Sysout(teststring.equals(Test.LETTER.getValue())); // Will return true
```

Of course you should provide a getter for the `value` attribute or let it be visible to the operation doing the comparison.

You could also code a `isEqual()` method in your `enum` like this:

```
enum Test {
    LETTER("1A");

    private String value;
    private Test(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isEqual(String value) { 
        return this.value.equals(value);
    }
}
```

And just do `Test.LETTER.isEqual(teststring)` to do this comparison.

Or even a `static getByValue(String value)` method to get the enum instance for a given `value`:

```
enum Test { 
    ...
    public static Test getByValue(String val) { 
        for (Test c : values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(val)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
    } 
} 

Test x = Test.getByValue("1A"); // x == Test.LETTER
```

Answer (score 8):

There are so much of other compiler errors in your code:

- `class enum Test` should be `enum Test`.
- An enum's constructor can only be `private`.
- Return type of `toString()` method is `void`. That is not a valid override. Make the return type `String`.

I don't know whether these errors also persist in your original code, or it's just a mistake in your post.

Now coming to the concrete question. When you print an `enum` constant, the `toString()` method is automatically called on that. So, you would get `1A` when you print `Test.LETTER`.

This is not true when passing `Test.LETTER` as argument to any method. You would have to call `toString()` explicitly. So, that should be:

```
System.out.println(teststring.equals(Test.LETTER.toString()));
```

---

Another way is to provide a method in your enum itself, which gets you an `enum` constant for a particular String value:

```
public static Test of(String str) {
    for (Test test: values()) {
        if (test.value.equals(str)) {
            return test;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can even cache the array returned by `values()` method, so that it not created again and again.

And then just compare the enum constant as:

```
String teststring = "1A";
System.out.println(Test.of(teststring) == Test.LETTER);
```

Comment: Thanks, of course these errors are not existent in my code, was just a (too) quick typo.

Comment: @RohitJain +1 But actually a potential problem can occur with the `of` function you provided. If you have `LETTER_B("1A"),LETTER("1A");` as enum constants, `Test.of(teststring) == Test.LETTER)` will return `false`. (even if this enum constans are actually stupid because they are basically the same)

Comment: @ZouZou Well that's true, but I wouldn't consider those cases in comparison, as you already said, those enums would be stupid. Using `==` to compare enum constants are perfectly acceptable practice. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1750435/1679863)

Comment: @Rohit Jain  “Using == to compare enum constants are perfectly acceptable practice.”— that’s true, but you are comparing `String`s using `==`. But that’s a different problem, a method returning a single object cannot handle the case when two objects match the condition.

Comment: @Holger Oops. That was a blunder from my side. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the check the following way and it will work

```
teststring.equals(Test.LETTER.toString())
```

`Test.LETTER` is an enum so it will never be equal to a String, but its value can be equal to a String so you have to check directly using the value of the enum.

Answer (score 0):

Because `String's equals` method is checking for the object received to be `String` as well. It should work if you try with `Test.LETTER.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

This will return false flag because of comparison between String object and ENUM instance.

If you do this:

```
String variable1 = "1A".
boolean flag = variable1.equals(Test.LETTER.value); 
system.out.println(flag);
```

This will return

```
True
```

all though

IN java **.equals** methods look like this

```
public final boolean equals(Object other) { 
    return this==other;
}
```

I always use == because it is null safe.

Comment: “IN java .equals and == are logically same” That’s completely wrong

Comment: Different classes have different implementations of `equals`. Since the question is about `String.equals` your statement remains wrong. And using `==` instead of `equals` when comparing `String`s is a bug.