# Detecting potential errors when converting String constants to enum

Tags: java, enums, refactoring, constants

I'm replacing a group of `String` constants with an `enum`, but the constants weren't used everywhere they should have been. So we're replacing a lot of `someValue.equals(FOO_CONST)` with `someValue == MyEnum.FOO`. It's easy to fix all the places where they were used--just delete the constants and the compiler tells you where the problems are. However, there are also bits like `"foo".equals(someValue)`, which the compiler can't identify as an error after the change is made.

Is there any way I can detect potential bugs caused by any of these inline literals that get missed during the conversion? (I'm using eclipse)

Comment: if "value" is still a String then you should not use value == MyEnum.VALUE because you would be comparing the reference of the object, which would always return false.

Comment: I was unclear but I'm talking about changing `value` to by an instance of `MyEnum` as well as using the enum values for comparison

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2937561/1393766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindBugs reports bugs for calls to `equals(Object)` when the two objects are not of the same type, which handles this problem nicely.

They will show up in the Bug Explorer under:

- Scariest

  - High confidence

    - Call to equals() comparing different types