# Equals Method in Enum Type

Tags: java, enums, equals

```
public enum EnumEqualsMethod {

    A,B,C

}


public enum EnumEqualsMethod1 {

    A,C,D

}

EnumEqualsMethod a =  EnumEqualsMethod.C;
ЕnumEqualsMethod1 b=  EnumEqualsMethod1.C;

System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

Output is `false`.Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Java enum members: == or equals()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals)

Comment: Because that are two different objects.

Comment: It's not because they have the same name that they are equals. Even if they are enums, they are still objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums are compared as Objects. These are two distinct objects of different classes. Why should they be equal? A,B,C - are just names of variables. They mean nothing in comparison operation.

Comment: we can't use equals method for constants in different enum classes.Right?

Comment: You should understand difference between reference, reference name and object. Once again reference names do not mean equality of objects.

Comment: You can use `equals()` for `enum` constants, but there's no point. It's the same as `==` for `enum`. One great thing about java `enum`s is that they each have their own name-space, so `C` in `EnumEqualsMethod` has nothing to do with `C` in `EnumEqualsMethod1`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why the output is false you should think of `EnumEqualsMethod` as a Class and `A, B, C` as *Instances* of that Class.

For example the comparison of the Enums is like doing the following:

```
Class1 a = new Class1();
Class2 b = new Class2();

System.out.print(a.equals(b));
```