# Why does comparing enums using == cause a PMD warning?

Tags: java, enums, comparison, pmd

The following compares two enum values using `==`:

```
MyEnum enum1 = blah();     // could return null
MyEnum enum2 = blahblah()  // could return null
if (enum1 == enum2) {
    // ...
}
```

But PMD gives a [CompareObjectsWithEquals](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/design.html#CompareObjectsWithEquals) warning on line 3:

> Use equals() to compare object references

Not sure I understand the [source code for this check](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/rules/design/CompareObjectsWithEquals.html) but thought it was OK to compare two enums using `==` so am wondering whether my code could be improved or the check is incorrect.

Comment: It is OK.  Might be relevant:  http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1028/

Comment: See also [Comparing Java enum members: == or equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is indeed accepted as bug:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1028/
- http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/909/

However, it seems to be tricky to catch all possible cases (quote from the newer bug):

> That one is a bit tricky, as in order to determine, whether a type is
>   a Enum, we need type resolution.
>
> I was able to adjust the rule to check, whether the type of the
>   variables is an Enum. This works only, if the Enum types are on the
>   "auxclasspath" of pmd, so that the type resolution can find it.
>
> Your example in isolation would still trigger this false positive, as
>   PMD doesn't know what ProcessingStatus is. I verified it with
>   java.math.RoundingMode, which is always on the classpath and will be
>   resolved.

("Your example" refers to the ticket author, not the OP on Stack Overflow)

Your case *might* work with PMD 5, the source you linked belongs to PMD 4.

Update: The [current source](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/f9b3f4ce4ae5888b10347e24e577256369156a1f/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/CompareObjectsWithEqualsRule.java) contains the additional check for enums:

```
 // skip, if it is an enum
 if (type0.getType() != null && type0.getType().equals(type1.getType()) && type0.getType().isEnum()) {
      return data;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to use `.equals()`, because [under the hoods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Enum.java#Enum.equals%28java.lang.Object%29), what happens is that the instances are compared with `==`.

```
public final boolean equals(Object other) {
    return this==other;
}
```

Note that this implementation of `.equals()` is `final`, which means you cannot override it in your enum.

Comment: Thanks - but either of the enums could be null so don't want to risk a NullPointerException.

Comment: Then you'll have to add a check. Or use the Java8's `Optional<T>` type. :)

Comment: Or stick to `enum1 == enum2` and ignore this PMD warning.