# Android Studio reports "Unreachable Code" with enum comparison

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm doing something that should be trivial- retrieving an enum value from a property and comparing it with a constant of that enum in an `if` statement. However Android Studio claims the `true` case is unreachable code and won't compile.

The block is:

```
if (ScanState.getScanMode() != ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE)
{
    //We're already scanning, but user wants to stop.
    stopScanning();
}
else
{
    ScanState.setScanMode(newMode);
    restartScan();
    buttonFlashMode = btnMode;
    buttonFlasher();
}
```

where in an extra `ScanState` class, I have:

```
public static ScanModeEnum getScanMode() {
    return scanMode;
}

public static void setScanMode(ScanModeEnum scanMode) {
    ScanState.scanMode = scanMode;
}

public enum ScanModeEnum
{
    SCAN_IDLE,
    SCAN_PERSON,
    SCAN_BIKE,
    SCAN_SEARCH
}

private static ScanModeEnum scanMode = ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE;
```

Variants I've tried, which Android Studio claims will all evaluate to `false` are

```
if(ScanState.getScanMode() == ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE)
if(ScanState.getScanMode().compareTo(ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE)!=0)
if(ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE == ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE)
if(ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE.equals(ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE))
```

I'm new to Java (more familiar with C#), but an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals) suggests that my understanding of this is sound. Is there some stupid mistake I'm making?

Comment: since you're not showing the complete method body, there are plenty hypotheses that could explain the error.

Comment: Rather than presenting snippets, are you able to transform this into a short but complete example? I agree it looks like everything should be reachable...

Comment: I don't see any reason why `ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE == ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE` would be false.

Comment: When I try it in some simple code, everything is reachable

Comment: Dito. Hard to say. Perhaps the `"ScanState".scanMode = scanMode; `troubles Android studio? Just guessing here.

Comment: Can confirm will421 here. Copy pasted your code and tried different values for scanMode and managed to land in different branches. Do you maybe set the scanMode to a fixed value before you do the if?

Comment: Maybe you just need to restart the IDE, enable Build Automatically, or other stupid thing related to the environment and not to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good grief. After making a seperate method as suggested and discovering the problem lay elsewhere I had a look further up the code. The complete method was;

```
public void onScanButtonPress(@ButtonFlashMode int button)
{
    ScanState.ScanModeEnum newMode;
    @ButtonFlashMode int btnMode = 0;

    switch (button)
    {
        case FLASH_BIKE:
            newMode = ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_BIKE;
            btnMode = FLASH_BIKE;

        case FLASH_PERSON:
            newMode = ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_PERSON;
            btnMode = FLASH_PERSON;

        default:
            //Unhandled.
            return;
    }

    if (ScanState.getScanMode() != ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE)
    {
        //We're already scanning, but user wants to stop.
        stopScanning();
    }
    else
    {
        ScanState.setScanMode(newMode);
        restartScan();
        buttonFlashMode = btnMode;
        buttonFlasher();
    }
}
```

Since I've forgotten to put `break` statements in the cases of the switch, it'll always return before the `if` is ever evaluated. It'll therefore never evaluate to `true` and so the error is correct- if misleading since it implies (to me at least!) that the `if` statement does get evaluated. Thanks for the comments, and I figured this was worth leaving (despite being indeed a stupid mistake) because others might be caught out by this.

Comment: With this code, the `if` line should be marked as the first unreachable line, not `stopScanning()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging this and verifying that the block is never actually reached?

I agree this is a very strange situation. If it persists, I can recommend swapping the enum for int constants, and conducting the check on them. It's not a real fix, but more of a workaround, but at least it can unblock you for the moment.

Comment: Debugging without compilation ?

Comment: You could have removed the if - else and tried to debug the comparison as a separate expression, just to verify it's value. But it doesn't matter, glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As mentioned by @Bubletan and @MarkoTopolnik, this would not result in a compiler error. Leaving the response as documentation of something that would NOT cause this error.

*Do you call anywhere in your code `setScanMode`? (outside that else block). The compiler may be detecting that the static variable scanMode is never modified, and therefore  `ScanState.getScanMode()` is always `ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE`, thus code not reachable.
Try invoking `setScanMode` somewhere in your code (with a value different than `ScanState.ScanModeEnum.SCAN_IDLE`) and see if this error disappears.*

Comment: I don't think so. It's a public method and therefore it could be called anywhere, even from a code which hasn't been written yet.

Comment: IntelliJ has no trouble flagging unused public methods.

Comment: @markoTopolnik but they shouldn't result in an error.

Comment: If you're talking about Java compiler errors, then the access level of the method doesn't matter at all. JLS specifies unreachable code within method as error; it doesn't deal with methods not being called. It also doesn't deal with the value of anything except local variables and compile-time constants.