# ContainsAll array list issue Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

So I'm trying to use the containsAll built in list method to compare two arrays

I used the contains method for single values and it works perfectly, however the contains all doesn't.

I'm making a card game so I'm checking whether a set of cards is also in another set of cards

so:

```
  if(this.hand.containsAll(hand.getCards())){
```

however this statement keeps returning false..

Here's the constructor

```
  private ArrayList<Card> hand;
     public Hand(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
            this();
            this.hand.addAll(hand);
        }
```

here's the get cards method

```
 public ArrayList<Card> getCards() {
        return this.hand;
    }
```

unsure as to why this code isn't returning true for containsAll but it's fine when done individually, is there some common concept that I haven't considered?

Any pointers would be a bonus

thank you

EDIT:

This returns true when used :

works

```
public boolean hasCard(Card card){
   if (this.hand.contains(card)){
       return true;
   }
}
```

doesn't

```
public boolean hasCards(Hand hand){
    if(this.hand.containsAll(hand.getCards()){
    return true
}
}
```

Main..

```
    Card one = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.CLUBS);
            Card two = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.DIAMONDS);
            Card three = new Card(Card.Rank.TWO, Card.Suit.SPADES);
            Card four = new Card(Card.Rank.SIX, Card.Suit.randSuit());
            Card five = new Card(Card.Rank.SEVEN, Card.Suit.randSuit());
            ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
            cards.add(one);
            cards.add(two);
            cards.add(three);
            cards.add(four);
            cards.add(five);
            Hand h = new Hand(cards);


   Card ones = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.CLUBS);
        Card twos = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.DIAMONDS);
        Card threes = new Card(Card.Rank.TWO, Card.Suit.SPADES);
        ArrayList<Card> cards2 = new ArrayList<>();

// works
h.hasCard(five);

// doesn't
h.hasCards(h2);


        cards2.add(ones);
        cards2.add(twos);
        cards2.add(threes);
        Hand h2 = new Hand(cards2);
```

Comment: Is `this.hand` a `Hand` or `List<Card>` instance?

Comment: List<Card> instance @Tunaki

Comment: Did you implement the `equals` method in the `Card` class?

Comment: No sir @yole, is that something I should avoid or do?

Comment: This is something you should read about, and then do.

Comment: I'll have a look, thank you @yole

Comment: You said that `contains` works? Show that code.

Comment: sure one moment @Dima check edit

Comment: That's not "code", it's just a single statement. Show complete reproducible example that works with `contains` and does not with `containsAll`.
Check out this link on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: better? @DIma i've made another edit

Comment: Maybe because `card` is in `this.hand` but not all objects in `hand.getCards()` are in `this.hand` so you get false. Are you sure that all objects in `this.hand` List are exactly same as in `hand.getCards()` List?

Comment: thats not the problem because even if I just have the singular value for hand.getCards() for containsAll that I used previous for contains I still get false @Atri

Comment: Could you show the complete code for that? A minimal complete version which can be copy pasted and compiled without any change.

Comment: No, not "better": `if(this.hand.containsAll(hand.getCards())` does not make any sense, because `this.hand`  and `hand` is the same thing, and you are treating it as a collection and as something that has `.getCards` at the same time

Comment: not the same thing, hence why I used this. @Dima, this. is referring the the object value and hand.getCards() is referring to the hand value passed in the argument.. thats just basic java

Comment: Share the complete code.

Comment: First of all, `h2` is defined below where you are using it.

Comment: @session_start there is no argument to that function, no local variable `hand`. Thus, `hand` and `this.hand` are the same thing in that scope.

Comment: You need to override the `equals()` method

Comment: I apologise @Dima, I corrected it

Comment: @session_start check my answer for "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `h.hasCard(new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.CLUBS))`. It fill return false. But this `h.hasCard(one)` returns true.

To understand why, try this: `one.equals(new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.CLUBS)`. These are two instances of the same card, but java has no way of knowing about it. They are two different objects.

You added `one` to your `h` hand, so, when looking for that object, you find it. But searching for another object `new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.CLUBS)` fails, because java does not know it represents the same card.

To fix this, you have to override the `equals` message on `Card`, and make it return true for objects that correspond to the same card.

Your `containsAll` call isn't working for the same reason: the hand contains all the cards, but they are represented by different objects. Implementing the `equals` method will fix that as well.

Comment: may I ask is my constructor    public Hand(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
        this();
        this.hand.addAll(hand);
    }
 a goodway to do it?

Comment: "A good way to do" ... _what_? Initialize the hand? It's ok ... I would declare the parameter as `List` or `Collection`, not `ArrayList`: the rule of thumb is to always use the most abstract interface level that fits your purpose.

Comment: so you'd have this.hand = new List<>();

Comment: No, you can instantiate `List`, it's an interface. I am talking about the constructor parameter type, not the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `equals` method.

When you do this:

```
Card five = new Card(Card.Rank.SEVEN, Card.Suit.randSuit());
h.hasCard(five);
```

You are essentially checking `(five == five)` which is true. This is because the default implementation of `equals()` method is (from the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)):

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Now when you have h2 containing the following cards:

```
Card ones = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.CLUBS);
Card twos = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.DIAMONDS);
Card threes = new Card(Card.Rank.TWO, Card.Suit.SPADES);
```

and `h` the following cards:

```
    Card one = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.CLUBS);
    Card two = new Card(Card.Rank.ACE, Card.Suit.DIAMONDS);
    Card three = new Card(Card.Rank.TWO, Card.Suit.SPADES);
    Card four = new Card(Card.Rank.SIX, Card.Suit.randSuit());
    Card five = new Card(Card.Rank.SEVEN, Card.Suit.randSuit());
```

And then you do:

```
h.hasCards(h2);
```

Then you are essentially checking if `ones, twos and threes` are present in `h`. Which is false, because for instance `ones` is **NOT** `==` any object in `h`.

You can check this for yourself by printing the value of `(ones == one)` which will be false.

Solution:

If you override the `equals()` method in your Class `Card` something like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    // Check if o == itself  
    if (o == this) {
        return true;
    }

    // Check to see if o is instance of Card or not
    if (!(o instanceof Card)) {
        return false;
    }

    // typecast o to Card to compare 
    Card c = (Card) o;

    // check equality (assuming Rank and Suit to be int, else you need to change equality condition here)
    return this.Rank == c.Rank
            && this.Suit == c.Suit;
}
```

Comment: Would the fact that I'm using enums be a problem? Also Complex isn't showing for me @Atri

Comment: @session_start sorry my bad, I was using my template of equals.

Comment: @session_start For comparing enums check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals

Comment: what is the point of the Card c= (Card) o when you're not using c? @Atri