# retrieving data from db with java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am very new to Java 8 features like streams, filters and stuff and the tell the truth, I haven't been writing in Java for more than a year.
Here is my problem if someone could give a suggestion .

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Agent> getAllEnabledAgents() throws Exception {    
    ArrayList<Agent> agents = repository.all(); //redis repository
    Stream<Agent> result = agents.stream().filter(a-> a.equals(a.getConfigState().Enabled));    //enum  
    return result; //I dont know how to return result or whether I am using stream correctly.

}
```

The main idea is that I want return all enabled agents. gerConfigState() returns an enum (__ConfigState). not sure If am doing this correctly.

Comment: Why fetch all of them from database and then filter the enabled ones in the memory? It's not a good Idea. Just fetch the enabled ones from database using a Criteria (where clause).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `collect`-metod of the `Stream`. Also, your filter looks a bit strange, since the variable `a` is an object of class `Agent`.

So perhaps something like this:

```
agents.stream()
      .filter(a -> a.getConfigState() == Enabled)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then again, like the comment states,  you might just be better off filtering this with a query.

Comment: I guess it looks strange. what about the return?

I've tried your code (and other stuff too) but it mostly complains "Can not convert from List<Agent> to Stream<Agent>

Comment: I've tried this yesterday. the result was something like that I can not compare enum state. getConfigState() returns enum state not a boolean

Comment: Where does it complain about this? Which line? If getConfigState() return an enum constant, you should be able to compare it with another enum constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter condition is not correct (I assume getConfigState() returns an enum).  You can use something like below:

```
Stream<Agent> streamAgent = agents.stream().filter(a-> a.getConfigState() == Enabled);    
return streamAgent.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is how I do it and it doesn't complain:
    Stream<Agent> result = agents.stream()
    .    filter(a-> a.getConfigState().equals("Enabled"));

I am going to write a junit test to chek int. One more thing... there is need of cast to <Agent> at the return.

Comment: You can use equals() or == to compare enum.  The pros and cons discussed here already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals.  I would prefer == as it safer.

Comment: Also you are comparing the enum string rather than the enum itself.  You should use a.getConfigState().equals(Enabled), passing in the actual enum, not the String.

Comment: this ius the way I do it now:
     
Stream<Agent> result = repository.all()
    .stream()
    .filter(a-> a.getConfigState()
    .equals(ConfigState.Enabled));
  return (ArrayList<Agent>) result.collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. This is the final version:

```
@Override
public List<Agent> getAllEnabledAgents() throws Exception {
      return repository.all()
            .stream()
            .filter(a-> a.getConfigState() == ConfigState.Enabled)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```