# Filter by enum class property Kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin

How do I filter by an enum class in kotlin? (just learning)
In the code below the enum class defined earlier in the file is `PayStatus{PAID,UNPAID}`.

```
fun nextRentDate(): LocalDate? {
            return rentPaymentSchedule.
                    filter { it.value.paymentStatus is PayStatus.UNPAID}.
                    minBy { it.value.date.toEpochDay() }?.value?.date
        }
```

I get the error: Kotlin:

> Incompatible types: PayStatus.UNPAID and Enum

Comment: Use `==` (or even `===` here), not `is`. is is for type checking (instanceof in Java). https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Comment: nice, yea i had tried `==` but was getting a different error, the root problem was that I had defined enum class in both the state file, and the contract file, so it was getting overridden by the wrong file defined enum class. all sorted, thanks!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must use the `==` operator when checking for enum values !

Comment: You could alternatively use `===` though it's essentially the same thing when it comes to enums

Answer (score 3):

The `is` keyword should be used for **type comparison**, as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators).
Using the operator for comparisons isn't possible as the compiler complains:

> 'is' over enum entry is not allowed, use **comparison** instead

[Comparison](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) in Kotlin comes in *two flavors*:  `==` and `===`

The first option, `==` is compiled down to `equals()`, whereas the latter, `===`, is equivalent to Java's `==` (comparing references).

As we know, this doesn't really make a difference with enums, as you can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals).