# For loop to search through 2D array in Java returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, nullpointerexception, 2d

For a project at University, I have to create a game of Tic Tac Toe.

I have this `for` loop with `if` statements to search through the 2D array of 3x3 size, and return if it's either `X` or `O` (enum). That results in showing which side has won the game.

However, the problem I have is that if the 2D array is not complete, as in if all the 9 boxes are not filled with `X` or `O`, the method shows a `NullPointerException`.

**Edit:** I have to add that I require the empty grid to be `null` as few other unit tests assume `grid[][]` is initialized as `null`.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at TicTacToeImplementation.whoHasWon(TicTacToeImplementation.java:80)
at ApplicationRunner.main(ApplicationRunner.java:24)
```

**Code:**

```
public enum Symbol {
    X, O
}

private Symbol winner;

public Symbol whoHasWon() {

    for (Symbol xORo : Symbol.values()) {

        if ((grid[0][0].equals(xORo) &&
                grid[0][1].equals(xORo) &&
                grid[0][2].equals(xORo))) {
            winner = xORo;
            isGameOver = true;

            break;
        } else if ((grid[1][0].equals(xORo) &&
                grid[1][1].equals(xORo) &&
                grid[1][2].equals(xORo))) {
            winner = xORo;
            isGameOver = true;

            break;}
           else if { //Code carries on to account for all 8 different ways of winning

        } else {

            isGameOver = true;
        }
    }

    return winner;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where is `grid` initialized? But, since enum values can (and should) be compared using `==`, change code to `grid[0][0] == xORo`, so a blank (aka `null`) cell will compare false, instead of throwing NPE.

Comment: You can check if not null before the equals method. Other way is fill all lines with something like any other character comma dot exc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple ways to ignore the "null" exception with an empty array.

The 1st way is to fill it with a different default symbol such as E. So when you initialize your arry at the beginning, instead of making it all empty and null, you can fill it with E's

```
for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
    for(int k=0;k<=2;k++){
        grid[i][k] = "E";
    }
}
```

Add this to beginning to fill it with E's first instead of nulls.

Another method is to find how to ignore the nulls using `try` or the following methods that can be found in this linkhttps://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/avoid-null-pointer-exception-in-java.html:

I won't be going into it because I believe the 1st method is easier to use and implement. However, depending on your requirements for your assignment, I would look at both just to be sure.

Hope this helps, Good luck!

Comment: I'm required to keep the null, as I also have some unit testing that requires initial values to be null. I'll have a look at the second one to avoid the null point exception. Also, it's only my 3rd week learning Java from the beginning so i'll probably need bit more direction

Comment: ha, only my 2nd week of learning java... but anyways I would check out that website I linked or just search up "ignore null pointer exception in java" in google

Answer (score 0):

You can change the comparasion of String.The code may be like this ;

```
public Symbol whoHasWon() {

    for (Symbol xORo : Symbol.values()) {

        if ((grid[0][0] == xORo.name() &&
                grid[0][1] == xORo.name() &&
                grid[0][2] == xORo.name())) {
            winner = xORo;
            isGameOver = true;

            break;
        } else if ((grid[1][0] == xORo.name() &&
                grid[1][1] == xORo.name() &&
                grid[1][2] == xORo.name())) {
            winner = xORo;
            isGameOver = true;

            break;}
        else if { //Code carries on to account for all 8 different ways of winning

        } else {

            isGameOver = true;
        }
    }

    return winner;
}
```

Enum like your's implemented

```
public enum Symbol{
        X, O
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750453/6214491) post, you can use either `equals()` or `==` to compare enums but using `==` is `null` safe while `equals()` isn't.

So basically, just write your checks like this:

```
if (grid[0][0] == xORo &&
    grid[0][1] == xORo &&
    // etc.
```

---

However, if you want to use the `equals()` method, you could just write a method that checks for `null` then compares the two values and returns the result:

```
public boolean isEqual(Symbol s1, Symbol s2) {
    if (s1 != null && s1.equals(s2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could then call the `isEqual()` method like this:

```
if (isEqual(grid[0][0], xORo) &&
    isEqual(grid[0][1], xORo) &&
    // etc.
```