# Implement uml Graph in Java

Tags: java, uml, enumeration, class-diagram

> What is a reasonable implementation of this uml graph in java?

[image]

where Enumeration,Eiche,Buche,Esche is german and means enum, oak, beech, ash. My attempt was the following

```
public class Material{

public static enum material{
oak, beech, ash
}

public int[] materialCost ={1,2,3};
}
```

The problem ist that somewhere in my homework-excercise I find `Table(Material.oak)` so I know my attempt must be wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In short

```
public enum Material {
    Eiche,Buche,Esche;
    public int materialCost; // public access is not great, but that's the model
}
```

### Detailed justification based on the UML diagram

The UML keyword `«enumeration»` corresponds in Java to an `enum`.

UML enumeration literals such as `Eiche`, `Buche`, `Esche`, are generally not underlined and are placed in a separate compartment with only literals.  This compartment should be graphically place below the operations, which are themselves sperated from the attributes. Your graphical notation does not respect this usage, so a closer look is needed to avoid confusion. Underlined elements in an UML class are static elements, but in the specific case of enumeration, the underline means an "instance specification" (sorry for the UML jargon) i.e. some constant enum values.

`materialCost` is not underlined.  It's therefore a normal, public attribute.  Some languages do not allow additional attributes and operations for an enumeration,  but UML does.  And fortunately Java as well.  We do not know the type of this attribute, so you could chose what is relevant in the implementation; `int` seems ok.  `materialCost` should not be an array: an array would require a multiplicity greater than 1 in UML since you could have more than one element. In the diagram there is no explicit multiplicity which means (according to the UML specs) a multiplicity of exactly 1.

Last but not least, the `materialCost` could perfectly be modified at any time according to the UML model,  since it is not followed by `{readOnly}`.  It's not an operation either since `()` is missing

### Additional remarks

In UML an enum is a value type:  if two instances have the same values they are considered as identical.
In Java it's a little more tricky, because of [the difference between `==` and `.equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1750435/3723423) and the special guarantees about `==` when comparing to enum literals and in absence of additional fields. SOme prudence seems advisable for this kind of hybrid enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually define attributes on Enum types pretty similarly to normal classes: [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

So in your example you could do something like

```
public enum Material {
    EICHE(1),
    BUCHE(2);

    private final int cost;

    Material(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    int cost() {
        return this.cost;
    }
}

...

Material oak = Material.EICHE;
System.out.println("One unit of Eiche costs " + oak.cost());
```

Comment: Nice answer.  But doesn't this implementation make  `cost` to remain unchanged once the enum constructed?  Wouldn't this make the cost  `{readOnly}` in UML, (which is not the case in the diagram)?

Comment: @Christophe yes, you're right - the `final` modifier is not fitting to the given model. I still think the aspect about initializing the cost of each material in the constructor (expressing that it is required to be set validly) is a noteworthy feature.