# compare To object enum

Tags: java

I have to create a method which tests if two object enum are equal.

Here is the code:

```
public Passenger{
     private String name_pass;
     public enum StatePass{
          b,c,p
     };
     private StatePass state;

     public Passenger(String name_pass,StatePass state){
            this.name_pass=name_pass;
            this.state=state;
     }

     public boolean isConfirmed(){
          if()
              return true;

          return false;      
     }
}
```

Inside the `if()` I have to check if the field state is equals to `p`.

How can I do that?

Comment: That code, even with a proper if, wouldn't compile. As StatePass is not an instance of State. But if you need to check if two objects are equal then just use the equals method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare enum values using ==, so your `if` can become

```
if( StatePass.p == state )
```

Note: in the constructor your second parameter must be a `StateClass` and not a `State` or you can never call `this.state=state`

Answer (score 2):

You can use both `equals()` and `==` to compare Java enums, so you may choose from

```
if(StatePass.p.equals(state))
```

or

```
if(StatePass.p == state)
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533922/is-it-ok-to-use-on-enums-in-java) for more info

Answer (score 0):

try using `state.equals(StatePass.p)`. Where is your problem?