# Check equality of a ENUM value with a String in JAVA

Tags: java, enums, equals, tostring

I know the correct way to do this is `Days.MONDAY.name().equals(day)`. But I'm wonder why `Days.MONDAY.equals(day)` fails when both prints MONDAY.

I know I'm missing something with equals() and toString(). I wanna clearly know what is it.

```
String day = "MONDAY";
System.out.println("main().Days.MONDAY : " + Days.MONDAY); // Prints MONDAY
System.out.println("main().day : " + day);// Prints MONDAY

System.out.println("main().Days.MONDAY.equals(day) : " + Days.MONDAY.equals(day)); // Why is this false when below is OK.
System.out.println("main().Days.MONDAY.toString().equals(day) : " + Days.MONDAY.toString().equals(day));// This is true
System.out.println("main().Days.MONDAY.name().equals(day) : " + Days.MONDAY.name().equals(day)); // This is true and I know this is the correct way
```

**Edit:** This is the enum.

```
enum Days{
    MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDENSDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY;
}
```

Comment: you are comparing a string with an enum - they can't be equal...

Comment: On `System.out.println("main().Days.MONDAY : " + Days.MONDAY);` implicit the `Days.MONDAY.toString()` method is called.

Answer (score 4):

The equals method of an Enum compares the Static instances of the Enum. Because any representation of an Enum is pointing to the same object instance.
So the equals method of the Enum is not comparing the Name or toString it compares the instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
String day="MONDAY";
```

The above line create `Object` inside **Constant Pool** , Where as

```
public enum Days{
MONDAY  <-- Created in HEAP
}
```

Now Coming to

```
Days.MONDAY.equals(day) --> Why False ?
```

`equals()` method of Enum  compares the  instances of the `Enum` not the `data` as `String#equals()` does !!

```
Days.MONDAY.toString().equals(day) --> Why true ?
```

because it is `String#equals()` method which is overloaded !!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [is-it-ok-to-use-on-enums-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533922/is-it-ok-to-use-on-enums-in-java).  Based on this, Java's implementation of equals on Enum simply performs ==.  Since the Enum and the `String day` in your example are not the same object, it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The methods of the class `Object` have a strictly defined contract.

One of those methods is the `Object.equals()` method - here is [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

To be able to maintain the *symmetry* requirement, it is practically impossible to return `true` in any implementation of `equals()` unless the two objects being compared are of the same class. `equals()` is supposed to represent some sort of equivalent between their properties, but objects which are not of the same class do not have the same properties.

Do not confuse the `Days` object `Days.MONDAY` with the string returned from `Days.MONDAY.toString()`. Its `toString()` just returns a string that represents it, and two strings are objects that can be equal. But `Days.MONDAY.toString()` is *not* the object itself (try `Days.MONDAY.equals( Day.MONDAY.toString() )` and you'll get false here, too!

When you send an object to the `print()` or `println()` methods of `System.out` or any other `PrintWriter`, `print()` will take that object's `toString()` value and print it. This is the reason why they "print the same thing". It is not actually the `MONDAY` object that's being printed (it's hard to define "printing an object"), it's the string `"MONDAY"` that's returned from its `toString()` method.

All this would hold true even if `Days` was not an enum but some other object that is not a string, though in the particular case of an enum, its `equals()` method is indeed a comparison of references rather than attributes.