# Generate new Enum value at runtime

Tags: java, enums

Suppose I have an Enum like this:

```
public enum BlaEnum{
    BLA1,
    BLA2;

    private static final String BLA_ONE = "bla one";
    private static final String BLA_TWO = "bla two";

    public static String getName(BlaEnum bla) {
        switch(bla) {
            case BLA1: return BLA_ONE;
            case BLA2: return BLA_TWO;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public static BlaEnum getBla(String bla) {
        switch(naam) {
            case BLA_ONE: return BLA1;
            case BLA_TWO: return BLA2;
            default: //return new enum value via reflection;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I, depending on the incoming String, return a new Enum value at runtime?
As if there would be an extra value declared:

```
public enum BlaEnum {
    BLA1, BLA2, EXTRA_BLA
...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can't.*

Comment: Just use a regular class.

Comment: * Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/534177/438154) if you're self destructive.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, because the current state of our software uses Enumerations where it now can be variable input...

Answer (score 3):

You can't. [Enums are constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

If you've run into a case in which you need to return a new enum value at runtime, then you should seriously rethink your design. What you probably need is is an actual class, or maybe some catchall enum value like "other".

Comment: Thanks! That's why I couldn't find the answer :).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with an enum. As it says in [JLS Sec 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants.

However, you can define an interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  // Add methods as required.
}
```

And have your enum implement this interface:

```
enum BlaEnum implements SomeInterface {
  BLA1, BLA2;
}
```

As well as a concrete class implementing the interface:

```
class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface {
  // ... whatever body
}
```

And have your `getBla(String)` method create an instance of `SomeInterfaceImpl` I N the default case, e.g.

```
default:
  return new SomeInterfaceImpl(bla);
```

(Obviously, the return type would need to be `SomeInterface`, rather than `BlaEnum`).

You might also want to use some sort of memoization if you want the same instance of `SomeInterfaceImpl` to be returned if the method is invoked multiple times with the same parameter.

Comment: I can't use this method since my value is mapped in Hibernate to an Enum (@Enumerated). I will have to redesign that part since sometimes, an unknown entity of Bla can be inserted...

Comment: @Valentin be sure to include all relevant details in your question.

Comment: actually, I asked what I wanted to know. You just tought me this, so I am glad I posed my question like this :).